# Inverse of property in Ember Template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have Boolean property `enableInput` that says whether the input is to be disabled or not. The `disabled` property of `input` need to be inverse of `enableInput`. How to do this **without using another property**?

```
{{input type='text' value=model.someValue disabled=invert(model.enableInput)}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inline-if` helper:

```
{{input type='text' value=model.someValue disabled=(if enableInput false true)}}
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/a5041ff14fe00d15fdd0)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/a5041ff14fe00d15fdd0)

Comment: Is this an Ember 2.0 feature?

Comment: It is a Ember v1.11 feature - http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_new-features-in-ember-js-1-11.